# stack smashing detected when use MPI_Reduce

Tags: c, mpi

I have learned to use some MPI functions. When I try to use `MPI_Reduce`, I get **stack smashing detected** when I run my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i, rank, size;
    int sendBuf, recvBuf, count;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    sendBuf = rank;
    count = size;
    MPI_Reduce(&sendBuf, &recvBuf, count, MPI_INT, 
        MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        printf("Sum is %d\n", recvBuf);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

It seem to be okey with my code. It will print **sum of all** rank in `recvBuf`with process 0. In this case, it will print `Sum is 45` if I run my code with 10 process `mpirun -np 10 myexecutefile`. But I don't know why my code has the error:

```
Sum is 45
*** stack smashing detected ***: example6 terminated
[ubuntu:06538] *** Process received signal ***
[ubuntu:06538] Signal: Aborted (6)
[ubuntu:06538] Signal code:  (-6)
[ubuntu:06538] *** Process received signal ***
[ubuntu:06538] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[ubuntu:06538] Signal code:  (128)
[ubuntu:06538] Failing at address: (nil)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node ubuntu exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: main should return an int.

Comment: I have tried to return an int, but it's still not corrected.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
MPI_Reduce(&sendBuf, &recvBuf, count, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The argument `count` must be the [number of elements in send buffer](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.8/man3/MPI_Reduce.3.php). As `sendBuf` is a single integer, try `count = 1;` instead of `count = size;`.

The reason why `Sum is 45` got correctly printed is hard to explain. Accessing values out of bound is undefined behavior: the problem could have remained unnoticed, or the segmentation fault could have been raised before `Sum is 45` got printed. The magic of undefined behavior...